# Windows Server Backup doesn't work when "Do not allow storage of credentials" GPO enabled

Tags: group-policy, credentials, windows-server-backup

I am getting a Windows Server Backup error which reads...

"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated"
Whenever I try to save a backup schedule.

In trying to diagnose this problem I've located this Microsoft post which says to "disable" the "Do Not allow storage of credentials or .NET Passports..." GPO as a solution to the problem.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968264/error-message-when-you-try-to-map-to-a-network-drive-of-a-dfs-share-by

I want to leave this GPO the way it is because cached passwords are a security liability that I cannot accept.

Is there an actual way to make Windows Server Backup function in a secure manner with this GPO setting enabled? I usually work around the problem in Task Scheduler by setting the task to run as SYSTEM, but this doesn't seem to work with Windows Server Backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [Powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Folders-and-System-State-e60faab7) to run Windows Server Backup under SYSTEM context?

Comment: Interesting! So I setup a backup schedule, make a PS script to run "Wbadmin start backup", set that to run with task scheduler as SYSTEM, and then disable Windows Server Backup from running automatically?

Comment: That's the idea although I must admit, I didn't try this combination myself. But there's usually no reason why it shouldn't work, I've never seen scheduled tasks fail under recent Windows OSes run under SYSTEM as long as you don't leave the machine with your task.

Comment: Little update on this issue; After some GPO tweaking I was finally able to create a backup schedule and create a task to run it via command line and output the results to a logfile. The weirdest thing happened after that; Regular backups started working again. The scheduled ones fail though. So instead of Windows Server Backup creating no meaningful error messages it now creates plenty of error messages. The important thing to me is that I get some automated backups for a little while before I need to revisit this.